# Java Error: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot

I get this warning message for the java below class code:

**Error message:** non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
cast to java.lang.Object for a varargs call
cast to java.lang.Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning

```
public class EntityNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

public EntityNotFoundException(Class<?> clazz, String... searchParamsMap) {
    super(EntityNotFoundException.generateMessage(clazz.getSimpleName(), toMap(String.class, String.class, searchParamsMap)));
}

private static String generateMessage(String entity, Map<String, String> searchParams) {
    return StringUtils.capitalize(entity) +
            " was not found for parameters:-> " +
            searchParams;
}

private static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(
        Class<K> keyType, Class<V> valueType, Object... entries) {
    if (entries.length % 2 == 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid entries");

    return IntStream.range(0, entries.length / 2).map(i -> i * 2)
            .collect(HashMap::new,
                    (m, i) -> m.put(keyType.cast(entries[i]), valueType.cast(entries[i + 1])),
                    Map::putAll);
}
```

}

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. Precision please. You haven't asked an actual question, but the answer to it is contained in the message.

Comment: Joop Eggen clarity, has really help me format my code...hence resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `Map.of(k0, v0, k1, v1, etc)`.

Type-safe but needing overloads for different number of map entries.

Your code has the problem that a `String...`/`String[]` is passed as an `Object...`. Which has the ambiguity - unrelated to any actual java rule -, that either one Object is passed with the String array, or every sole String is passed as a separate Object.

Simply specify

```
<K, V, E /*super K & V*/> toMap(Class<K> keyType, Class<V> valueType, E[] entries) {
```

This allows pervasively passing a String array. I am unsure whether E cannot be more restricted to K and V. Hence out-commented.

Comment: thanks  Joop Eggen for the clarification...its helpful